# Getting time from string timezone (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, time

Is there is any npm package available for getting time from string?
Using gmt+5 for Example

```js
let time = something("gmt+5")
```

Now `time` is a date object.
If there is any package for doing this, please let me know.

Comment: I'm curious to see, what kind of a date you're expecting your example to parse from the bare timezone.

Comment: What would be the expected outcome? The current time in GMT+5?

Comment: Yes, the current time in GMT+5 @derpirscher

Comment: Why would you need a package for this? It's a couple of lines of code only.

Comment: @Teemu oh i didn't know that. could you show me the code

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***>>>[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+timezone+offset+to+date+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Parse your gmt string to milliseconds (zone), then get the time of the current date (it's in UTC) and add the zone and the current timezone offset (in msecs), make a new date of the result and that's it. Three lines of code, literally.

Comment: Three lines provides the offset being in decimal hours, the complexity of parsing increases, if the offset is in hours and minutes. There's a flaw in the date object, though. No matter what's the value of the date, the timezone offset of the date is always your local timezone in the object, that makes the calculated date suitable for representative purposes only, if you want to make math with the object, you've to take the timezone into account again.

Comment: @Teemu—re "*the timezone offset of the date is always your local timezone in the object*" is incorrect. Date objects don't have a timezone, they're inherently UTC. The offset returned by *getTimezoneOffset* is from system settings, not the Date object. A Date can be presented for any timezone/representative location using *toLocaleString* and IANA representative location.

Comment: @RobG Maybe poor wording, but when you stringify a date, you can see the "timezone offset", ex. GMT+2 EET, that doesn't change, no matter what time you set to the time of the date instance, because it's taken from the system, like you said. The system time is not necessarily "your local", of course.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into `date-fns` and `date-fns-tz`?

Using IANA timezones you could get the current time in another timezone.

Example

```js
var now = new Date();
const daressalaam = zonedTimeToUtc(now, "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam");
const sydney = zonedTimeToUtc(now, "Australia/Sydney");
const copenhagen = zonedTimeToUtc(now, "Europe/Copenhagen");

console.log(daressalaam)
console.log(sydney)
console.log(copenhagen)
```

Output

```
Thu Mar 11 2021 09:24:20 GMT+0100 
Thu Mar 11 2021 01:24:20 GMT+0100 
Thu Mar 11 2021 11:24:20 GMT+0100
```

Quick Sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-banach-om1c7?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You can do this without a library using the [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) (or [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)) and suitable options.

Comment: @RobG That would just return formatted strings instead of `Date` object. Right?

Comment: Yes. Date objects don't have a timezone, they are just an offset (time value) from the ECMAScript epoch so are inherently UTC. "Now" has exactly the same time value in every timezone. What your code above does is effectively set "now" as the time in the specified location, then prints the equivalent time in the client current location. I.e. the apparent offset is in the opposite direction to that expected. In the output, all the offsets are +1. Sydney (+11) should be 10 hours ahead of Copenhagen (+1), but the output shows it 10 hours behind.

Comment: Ah I see it now, thanks for clearing it up! I didn't catch that Sydney vs Copenhagen was in the wrong direction. I guess just emphasized on OP wanting `time` as an `Date` object and not a localized/formatted string.